# R: No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping

I am working with the R programming language.

I am trying to run the following code in R:

```
ips <- c(Louvre           ="213.139.122.103",
         British.Museum   ="195.224.71.221",
         Museo.del.Prado  ="213.27.146.137",
         Grand.Egyptian   ="163.121.93.15",
         Hermitage.Museum ="213.152.151.197",
         MBNA             ="200.218.240.120",
         Sydney.Museum    ="54.252.89.136",
         MOMA             ="63.117.124.131")

.
library(XML)
library(httr)
get.geocode <- function(ip) {  # returns lat/long given an ip address
  url   <- "http://www.freegeoip.net"
  xml   <- content(GET(url,path=paste("xml",ip,sep="/")),type="text/xml")
  xpath <- c(lat="//Latitude",long="//Longitude")
  sapply(xpath,function(xp) as.numeric(xmlValue(xml[xp][[1]])))
}

locs <- data.frame(t(sapply(ips,get.geocode)))
```

Everything seems to run fine until the last line - then I get this error:

```
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
 Error in read_xml.raw(x, encoding = encoding, ...) : 
  Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 9 and head [76]
```

I tried to individually search for them to see if this might work - but I get the same error:

```
> get.geocode("63.117.124.131")
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
 Error in read_xml.raw(x, encoding = encoding, ...) : 
  Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 9 and head [76]
```

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?**

Thanks!

Comment: `http://www.freegeoip.net`  redirects to `https://ipstack.com`, looks like you now need an API key to get query result. After 100 queries / mo, you'll have to pay for the service

Comment: You can try https://www.ip2location.io for the json results.

Comment: @ Waldi: Thank you for your reply! I wonder if there is another free source?

Comment: @ Michael C. : Thank you for your reply! Is there a way to use the search this site in a more effective way? For example, instead of https://www.ip2location.io/ ... can I do https://www.ip2location.io/213.139.122.103 ?

Comment: @stats_noob You can do `ipinfo.io/213.139.122.103` . Just plug the IP address at the end of the URL of ipinfo.io. This will return a JSON response. The documentation of IPinfo is available here >> https://ipinfo.io/developers

Comment: Yes, you can use it as API endpoint https://api.ip2location.io/?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&ip=8.8.8.8&format=json